# Read RSS Feed from sites and Display HTML content from it using C#

Tags: c#, html, wpf, web

I am looking for a suitable way to read and display RSS Feed from the below showed websites :-

http://feeds.feedburner.com/zerohedge/feed

http://www.nirmaltv.com/feed/

Below is the code that I used for reading RSS Feed from the above web sites.

```
  public virtual IList<NewsFeedItem> ParseRss(string url)
  {
    try
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(url);

        var entries = from item in doc.Root.Descendants().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "channel").Elements().Where(i => i.Name.LocalName == "item")
                      select new NewsFeedItem
                      {                                  
                          Content = item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "description").Value,
                          Link = item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "link").Value,
                          PublishDate = ParseDate(item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "pubDate").Value),
                          Title = item.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "title").Value
                      };
        return entries.ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new List<NewsFeedItem>();
    }
}

private DateTime ParseDate(string date)
{
    DateTime result;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(date, out result))
        return result;
    else
        return DateTime.MinValue;
}

public class NewsFeedItem
{
 public string Link { get; set; }
 public string Title { get; set; }
 public string Content { get; set; }
 public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }        

  public NewsFeedItem()
  {
    Link = string.Empty;
    Title = string.Empty;
    Content = string.Empty;
    PublishDate = DateTime.Today;            
  }
}
```

And this code is used in the load event of a WPF Window. This WPF application has a Window, which contains a List box. I am trying to show the RSS feed into the WPF list box [or please suggest any other best control to display the RSS feed].

```
 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate {
        Window parser = new Window ();
        var items = parser.ParseRss(Url);
        lstbox.ItemsSource = items;
        });
    }
```

When I do the "parsing of these websites" using the ParseRss method, i am getting HTML formatted string (which means the string starts with paragraph tag or a href tag etc).

I want to display corresponding web page or web content as per the HTML formatted string in the list box.
 How this is possible ?

the XAML window is ;

```
    <ListBox x:Name="lstbox" Height="300" Width="500" 
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="3">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="1" Margin="3" CornerRadius="5" Height="260" Width="500">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Background="DarkGray" Foreground="AntiqueWhite" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Title}" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="3" Text="{Binding Link}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PublishDate}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>                   
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following xml linq.  I looks like description and encoded are the same.  See code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string URL = "http://www.nirmaltv.com/feed/";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(URL);
            XElement channel = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = channel.GetDefaultNamespace();
            XNamespace nsContent = channel.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("content");
            XNamespace nsRDF = channel.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("rdf");

            List<Item> items = doc.Descendants(ns + "item").Select(x => new Item()
            {
                title = (string)x.Element(ns + "title"),
                link = (string)x.Element(ns + "link"),
                comments = (string)x.Element(ns + "comments"),
                pubDate = (DateTime)x.Element(ns + "pubDate"),
                category = (string)x.Element(ns + "category"),
                guid = (string)x.Element(ns + "guid"),
                description = (string)x.Element(ns + "description"),
                encoded = (string)x.Element(nsContent + "encoded"),
                sequence = (string)x.Element(nsRDF + "Seq"),
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class Item
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string link { get; set; }
        public string comments { get; set; }
        public DateTime  pubDate { get; set; }
        public string category { get; set; }
        public string guid { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string encoded { get; set; }
        public string sequence { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note : The code was working and just started giving me a 401 error.

Comment: You have to add the code to put into Listbox.  Add binding source.

Comment: Yes i have done the UI changes. Thanks for your help. But some html tag starts with <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"  and not able to parse it properly. What to do in such situations ???

Comment: this url -  https://hartford.craigslist.org/search/sss?format=rss&query=nest%20thermostat starts with <rdf RDF xmlns rdf=....

Comment: I tried with your latest code, but still it is not working. The List<Item> items is always 0 at the end.

Comment: Is the link accurate?  It doesn't looks like other links.  The node "Seq" starts with a capital letter.  And the node is "items" instead of "item".